# when i trying to post on mysql it gives me " java.lang.NullPointerException "

Tags: java, android, mysql, rest, android-studio

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
    String JSPN_Request = "";
    String response = "";
    URL url = null;
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = null;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try
    {
        url = new URL(strings[0]);
        jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("userId",102);
        jsonObject.put("id",102);
        jsonObject.put("title","hello world");
        jsonObject.put("body","hello world");

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        bufferedWriter.write(jsonObject.toString());
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            break;
        }
        reader.close();
        response = sb.toString().toString();

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "----------------------------------json-error----------------------------------");
        Log.d(TAG, "POSTING ERROR" + e);
        Log.d(TAG, "----------------------------------json-error----------------------------------");
    }}
```

when i trying to post to database i get this error and i searched alot but nothing.
i'm using localhost to post this data using url (10.0.3.0:8000/post)
as i'm using genymotion emulator
thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions should be posted as [mcve]s. In this case your question is a duplicate, but when posting you should also include the stack trace (Error)

Comment: @mina madgy use try catch in connection

Comment: She already did, it's in the example, although it is not the solution @PauloRodrigues

Comment: @NickCardoso she needs to put in         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 to check connection, the error comes from         url = new URL(strings[0]);

Comment: @NickCardoso not duplicate. The problem is more subtle this time.

Answer (score 0):

Because you closed the OutputStream. Doing so closes the connection and resets it.

Any calls to `close()` on the connection or it's streams must be after you're done reading and writing it.

```
    bufferedWriter.write(jsonObject.toString());
    bufferedWriter.flush();
    bufferedWriter.close();
//    outputStream.close(); remove from here
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        break;
    }
    reader.close();
    response = sb.toString().toString();
catch(Exception ex) {
    ...
}
finally {
    if (outputStream != null) outputStream.close(); // move it here
}
```